# How to setup Tomcat web.xml and context.xml for 2 different (user and admin) authentication

Tags: tomcat, authentication, jdbcrealm

Here's my situation:

I want stuff under

mysite/customer/*

to require form-based authentication before access (login via mysite/customer/login.jsp, with its own user_password table and role. )

BUT

I want stuff under

mysite/admin/*

to require *another* form-based authentication before access (login via mysite/admin/login.jsp, with another set of admin_user_password table and role. )

Is it possible to do this under Tomcat 6.0? If so, can someone briefly describe how I could go about implementing this? I've looked around and only seen examples of 1 Realm setup...havent seen multiple Realm setup before.

I use JDBCRealm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that is not possible.  You could go the filter way in which you setup a filter for the  customer side of your tree and another filter for the admin side.  Take a look [here](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/Filters.html).

The other way is to setup two applications in tomcat in two different contexts using single sign on within tomcat.  In this way you would have `/mysitecustomer` and `mysiteadmin` as two different applications sharing one realm but having two different login pages.

Answer (score 0):

BTW - from my reading, the Context is the preferred mechanism.  I am setting up the model for my consulting business for partitioning customers that need some hosted web app and staging it on my server for my convenience.